# Partition dataset using CART regression by leaf node

Tags: r, regression

I'm currently trying to modify an existing Stata model in R, and I'm running into problems with a specific step in the process.

I need to use a CART regression to divide my dataset up into individual clusters based on their leaf node, such that each leaf node becomes a new dataset.

For example, lets say that my regression results in a tree as follows:

```
        Root
        /   \
     ALeft  ARight
    /     \
BLeft    BRight
          /   \
       CLeft  CRight
```

I would like to then take my dataset, and for each instance determine (analogous to the typical predict method) which leaf node it belongs to, of the set (ARight,BLeft,CLeft,CRight).

Are there any existing packages, or methods for the rpart/tree CART models, which would allow me to output the leaf node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd find the rpart package useful, particularly the `where` element.

**where**: an integer vector of the same length as the number of observations in the root node, containing the row number of frame corresponding to the leaf node that each observation falls into.

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit$where
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
9  7  9  9  3  3  3  3  3  8  8  3  9  5  3  3  3  7  3  5  3 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 
9  8  9  9  5  9  8  3  3  3  7  7  3  7  3  5  9  5  8  9  5 
43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 
9  9  3  7  3  7  9  7  8  3  9  3  3  3  5  9  5  8  9  9  9 
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
3  3  5  3  7  5  3  7  7  3  7  3  3  7  5  7  9  5
```

Comment: In addition to in-sample `$where` you can get out-of-sample predictions if you convert the rpart object to the party class from `library("partykit")`, e.g., `predict(as.party(fit), newdata = data.frame(Age = 80, Number = 4, Start = 11), type = "node")`. The same is possible for the trees from partykit itself, of course (ctree, lmtree, glmtree, ...).